# Порадьте книги або посібники, якими користуєтеся для дослідження наголосів

Tags: наголос, resource-request

Які книги з української мови найкраще розтолковують правила щодо наголосу? Незрозуміло, як пояснити іноземцям те, що наголос рухомий і як його рухати.

Comment: Стосовно запитань про джерела, тут така історія. (1) взагалі-то, на Stack Exchange не дуже заохочуються запитання, які запрошують до відповідей, які містять необмежений список чогось (бо такі відповіді схильні до того, щоб бути субʼєктивними, і серед кількох відповідей неможливо обрати «правильну»); (2) ми мали [дискусію](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/40/) на цю тему, наразі наш висновок — краще такі запитання тримати на [meta];

Comment: (3) що ми, власне, і робимо: [за оцим тегом](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) маємо кілька дописів, де зберігаються **списки джерел**; (4) [оця відповідь](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/130/8) має секцію, яка стосується наголосів, і в сусідніх відповідях ще трошки є.

Answer (score 2):

Наголос можна перевірити на сайті [Словники України online](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/), а також в [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/) деякі слова.

Словник-довідник [Складні випадки наголошення](https://www.twirpx.com/file/300334/)